# Create a boxplot in ggplot with two vectors that have different sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, geom

I am trying to create a `geom_boxplot()` from two vectors but without any data frames. I can do this easily with the generic `boxplot`.

Given the following vectors:

```
runtimeWithA <- sample(20:37, size = 288, replace = TRUE)
runtimeWithoutA <- sample(35:37, size = 128, replace = TRUE)
```

I can create a simple with

```
boxplot(runtimeWithA, runtimeWithoutA, 
         names = c("withA", "withoutA"), 
         ylab = "s (lower is better)", 
         main = "Runtime withA vs withoutA")
```

[image: Image of Plot]

I can't seem to be able to achieve the same thing with `gg_plot` and `geom_plot`. And I can't create a dataframe from the two vectors because they are not the same size. I would prefer to use ggplot() because it would be easier to attach extra text to the graph i.e. mean.

Trying to get a similar result as above with ggplot gave me the following errors.

```
ggplot(data = NULL, mapping = aes(y = runtimeWithA, y = runtimeWithoutA)) + 
 geom_boxplot()
```

> ```
> Error in aes(y = runtimeWithA, y = runtimeWithoutA) :    formal
> argument "y" matched by multiple actual arguments
> ```

```
ggplot(data = NULL) + 
 geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(runtimeWithA, runtimeWithoutA))
```

> ```
> Error in `check_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or
> the same as the data (288): y
> ```

Is this impossible with `ggplot()` or there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the x-axis values in two geom_boxplots.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x="WithA", y=runtimeWithA)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x= "WithoutA", y=runtimeWithoutA)) +
  ggtitle("Runtime withA vs withoutA") + 
  ylab("s (lower is better)") + 
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Spent an entire day trying to figure this out before deciding to ask.